# How to do a submit on a contact us form, rails 4

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

I am a newbie in ror, working on a simple static page showing a portfolio of images. Its one long static page, at the end of the page I am trying to add a contact US form, I found some code like this

```
 <div id="contact"> <span class="largetext section">CONTACT</span> </div>
  <div class="horizantal_rule"></div>
  <div class="container">
    <form action="http://Somesite/form.php" method="post">  // This is the area I need to replicate in rails 4
      <div class="cf_left">
        <label for="cf_email">Email Address</label>
        <input class="login-form1" type="text" name="cf_email" id="cf_email">
        <label for="cf_name">Name</label>
        <input class="login-form1" type="text" name="cf_name" id="cf_name">
        <label for="cf_industry">Industry</label>
        <input class="login-form1" type="text" name="cf_industry" id="cf_industry">
      </div>
      <div class="cf_center">
        <label for="cf_message">Your Message</label>
        <textarea class="login-form1" type="text" name="cf_message" id="cf_message"></textarea>
        <input class="login-form1" type="submit" value="">
      </div>
      <div class="cf_right">
        <p>Contact Us Directly</p>
        <a href="mailto:info@somesite.com" class="apptext">info@somesite.com</a>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
```

Now in the HTML code the form action is using a php form, I am assuming I am replacing this with rails functionality, Can someone give me a good simple solution just to perform a mailto to task or just forward the data entered to a specific email?

Thanks.

Comment: You're going to need _at the very least_ a controller to handle the submitted request and _possibly_ a model to hold the data you collect.  Unfortunately, this is off-topic for SO, but I suggest getting started by checking out the RoR tutorials at http://ruby.railstutorial.org/book/ruby-on-rails-tutorial

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to approach this problem, but the simplest is arguably:

1. [create a `ContactsController` to handle form submission, error handling and redirection](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html)
2. [add the appropriate routes for your controller action](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html)
3. [use `form_tag` to construct and wire up a form in your static page](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#a-generic-search-form)
4. [add input elements to your form using the various form helpers](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#helpers-for-generating-form-elements)

From here, you could investigate making your form remote (i.e. AJAX), creating a Contact RESTful resource and adding unit/integration tests.

Comment: for the controller , does it matter if I tell you that my entire ap is just one html called home.html.erb, and I just want to add to the bottom of it this contact form? Am I wrong in assuming that each action controller = new html page?

Comment: If you were taking a RESTful approach, you'd (mostly) be correct.

Comment: Also, an alternative to creating a `ContactsController` would be to add a `contact` action to your `ApplicationController`.